# Traversing and enumerating a directory with multi-threads

Tags: java, multithreading, search

I am running a thread to traverse my local directory (no sub directory) and as soon as I am getting a text file, I am starting a new thread which will search a word in that file.

What is wrong in the below code?

Searching and traversing are working fine, separately. But when I am putting it together, some thing is going wrong, it is skipping some files (Not exactly, due to multithreading object sunchronization is not happening properly).

Please help me out.

**Traverse.java**

```
    public void executeTraversing() {
            Path dir = null;
            if(dirPath.startsWith("file://")) {
                    dir = Paths.get(URI.create(dirPath));
            } else {
                    dir = Paths.get(dirPath);
            }
            listFiles(dir);
    }

    private synchronized void listFiles(Path dir) {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
                    for (Path file : stream) {
                            if (Files.isDirectory(file)) {
                                    listFiles(file);
                            } else {
                                    search.setFileNameToSearch(file);
                                    executor.submit(search);
                            }
                    }
            } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {
                    // IOException can never be thrown by the iteration.
                    // In this snippet, it can only be thrown by
                    // newDirectoryStream.
                    System.err.println(x);
            }
    }
```

**Search.java**

```
    /**
     * @param wordToSearch
     */
    public Search(String wordToSearch) {
            super();
            this.wordToSearch = wordToSearch;
    }

    public void run() {
            this.search();    
    }

    private synchronized void search() {
            counter = 0;

            Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
            try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(fileNameToSearch.toAbsolutePath(), charset)) {
                    // do you have permission to read this directory?
                    if (Files.isReadable(fileNameToSearch)) {
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    counter++;
                                    //System.out.println(wordToSearch +" "+ fileNameToSearch);

                                    if (line.contains(wordToSearch)) {
                                            System.out.println("Word '" + wordToSearch
                                                            + "' found at "
                                                            + counter
                                                            + " in "
                                                            + fileNameToSearch);
                                    }
                            }
                    } else {
                            System.out.println(fileNameToSearch
                                            + " is not readable.");
                    }

            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
            }

    }
```

Comment: ...what exactly is the failure?

Comment: Fisrt of all, there are some syntax errors involving the `try-catch` statements.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did debugging and found that just before the search.setFileNameToSearch(file);
found that it is printing all the file names correctly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   while debugging out put is coming as expected, correctly. I don know what is happening

Comment: @tbodt I am using Java 7. and I am not getting any compilation error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this Search instance that you keep reusing here:

```
search.setFileNameToSearch(file);
executor.submit(search);
```

while its actual search() method is synchronized, it appears like by the time it actually gets to searching something `setFileNameToSearch()` would have been called several times, which would explain the skipping.

create a new instance of `Search` each time, then you wouldnt need to sync the actual `search()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the `ExecutorService` inside your `listFiles` method, this is probably not a good idea: because of that you're probably creating too many threads.

On top of that you're not monitoring the state of all these `ExecutorServices`, some of them might not be started when you application stops

Instead you should create the `ExecutorService` only once, before starting the recursion. When the recursion is over, call `shutdown()` on your ExecutorService to wait for all tasks completion

Furthermore you are reusing a `Search` object and passing it to mutliple tasks while modifying it, you should create a Search for each file you're processing